# Get list of string from string with regex C#

Tags: regex

Consider I have a string like this:

```
"apple {20} okay then {23} fine {10} fruits {ko}"
```

I would like to get list of all string which begin with "{" and end with "}" and the text within should in numeric.

The result I should get:

```
"{20}"
"{23}"
"{10}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you may try this,

```
\{\d+\}
```

`\d+` matches one or more digit characters. Since `{`, `}` are special chars in regex, you must escape those in-order to match the literal form of those characters.